# Prove inequality involving $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R_+$ with $a+b+c+d=1$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Prove the following. Let $a,\,b,\,c,\,d$ be nonnegative real numbers that sum to 1. Define: 
\begin{equation}
x_1 = \min(a+b,\, c+d)\;,\qquad
x_2 = \min(a+c,\, b+d)\;,\qquad
x_3 = \min(a+d,\, b+c)\;.
\end{equation}
Then, it holds that $x_1 \leq x_2+x_3$, and all other inequalities obtained by permuting the indices 1,2,3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a\geq b\geq c\geq d$.

Thus, $$\min\{a+b,c+d\}=c+d\leq b+d=\min\{a+c,b+d\},$$

which says that it's enough to prove our statement in two following cases.

1. $$\min\{a+b,c+d\}+\min\{a+d,b+c\}\geq\min\{a+c,b+d\}.$$

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$c+d+\min\{a+d,b+c\}\geq b+d$$ or
$$c+\min\{a+d,b+c\}\geq b.$$
a) $a+d\geq b+c$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$c+b+c\geq b,$$ which is obvious;

b) $a+d\leq b+c$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$c+a+d\geq b,$$ which is obvious again;

2. $$\min\{a+b,c+d\}+\min\{a+c,b+d\}\geq\min\{a+d,b+c\}.$$

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$c+d+b+d\geq\min\{a+d,b+c\} $$ or
$$c+b+2d\geq \min\{a+d,b+c\}.$$
a) $a+d\geq b+c$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$c+b+2d\geq b+c,$$ which is obvious;

b) $a+d\leq b+c$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$c+b+2d\geq a+d$$  or
$$c+b+d\geq a,$$ which is true because
$$a\leq b+c-d\leq b+c+d.$$
Done!

Comment: Nice job! I think it is also true the reverse statement: if $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are any three numbers such that $0\leq x_i\leq 1/2$ and $x_1\leq x_2+x_3$ (and its permutations), then the $x_i$ can be written as above, for suitable $a,b,c,d\geq 0$ which sum to 1.

Comment: @wolf99 I think the condition $a+b+c+d=1$ is unnecessary.